# JQuery Populate Table by Columns

Tags: jquery, html, loops, html-table

I'm looking for a way to populate a table based on column heading. My data will be coming from a database based upon date. In the past I would use floating DIVs with a 1 column table inside of it, however, I was recently told it's possible through JQuery. I looked through previous stacks and saw similar requests, but none are what I'm looking for.

The top table headings will 'days of the week' (Mon | Tues | Weds | etc) and then the first column will contain the titles of various statistics that will be pulled and displayed in their respective rows per each day.

When pulling my data from my database, it will be grouped by date so I'd need to populate column 2, then 3, then 4, etc.

```
<table>
<thead>
    <th class="bluetitle">Metrics</th>
    <th class="blacktitle">Sun</th>
    <th class="blacktitle">Mon</th>
    <th class="blacktitle">Tue</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Combined SLA</td>
        <td data-day="sun">0</td>
        <td data-day="mon">0</td>
        <td data-day="tue">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="category " id="1">
        <td>OCIO</td>
        <td data-day="sun"></td>
        <td data-day="mon"></td>
        <td data-day="tue"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub" id="1_1" data-parent="1">
        <td>Phone</td>
        <td data-day="sun">11</td>
        <td data-day="mon">11</td>
        <td data-day="tue">11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subsub" id="1_1_1" data-parent="1_1">
        <td>Queued For Answer</td>
        <td data-day="sun">111</td>
        <td data-day="mon">111</td>
        <td data-day="tue">111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subsub" id="1_1_2" data-parent="1_1">
        <td>Answered > 30 sec</td>
        <td data-day="sun">112</td>
        <td data-day="mon">112</td>
        <td data-day="tue">112</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subsub" id="1_1_3" data-parent="1_1">
        <td>Abandoned > 30 sec</td>
        <td data-day="sun">113</td>
        <td data-day="mon">113</td>
        <td data-day="tue">113</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub" id="1_2" data-parent="1">
        <td>Email</td>
        <td data-day="sun">12</td>
        <td data-day="mon">12</td>
        <td data-day="tue">12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subsub" id="1_2_1" data-parent="1_2">
        <td>Email Tickets Created</td>
        <td data-day="sun">121</td>
        <td data-day="mon">121</td>
        <td data-day="tue">121</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subsub" id="1_2_2" data-parent="1_2">
        <td>Created > 60 min</td>
        <td data-day="sun">122</td>
        <td data-day="mon">122</td>
        <td data-day="tue">122</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub" id="1_3" data-parent="1">
        <td>Chat</td>
        <td data-day="sun">13</td>
        <td data-day="mon">13</td>
        <td data-day="tue">13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subsub" id="1_3_1" data-parent="1_3">
        <td>Queued for Answer</td>
        <td data-day="sun">131</td>
        <td data-day="mon">131</td>
        <td data-day="tue">131</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subsub" id="1_3_2" data-parent="1_3">
        <td>Answered > 30 sec</td>
        <td data-day="sun">132</td>
        <td data-day="mon">132</td>
        <td data-day="tue">132</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subsub" id="1_3_3" data-parent="1_3">
        <td>Abandoned > 30 sec</td>
        <td data-day="sun">133</td>
        <td data-day="mon">133</td>
        <td data-day="tue">133</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="category" id="2">
        <td>OCFO</td>
        <td data-day="sun"></td>
        <td data-day="mon"></td>
        <td data-day="tue"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub" id="2_1" data-parent="2">
        <td>Phone</td>
        <td data-day="sun">21</td>
        <td data-day="mon">21</td>
        <td data-day="tue">21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subsub" id="2_1_1" data-parent="2_1">
        <td>Queued For Answer</td>
        <td data-day="sun">211</td>
        <td data-day="mon">211</td>
        <td data-day="tue">211</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subsub" id="2_1_2" data-parent="2_1">
        <td>Answered > 30 sec</td>
        <td data-day="sun">212</td>
        <td data-day="mon">212</td>
        <td data-day="tue">212</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subsub" id="2_1_3" data-parent="2_1">
        <td>Abandoned > 30 sec</td>
        <td data-day="sun">213</td>
        <td data-day="mon">213</td>
        <td data-day="tue">213</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub" id="2_2" data-parent="2">
        <td>Email</td>
        <td data-day="sun">22</td>
        <td data-day="mon">22</td>
        <td data-day="tue">22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subsub" id="2_2_1" data-parent="2_2">
        <td>Email Tickets Created</td>
        <td data-day="sun">221</td>
        <td data-day="mon">221</td>
        <td data-day="tue">221</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subsub" id="2_2_2" data-parent="2_2">
        <td>Created > 60 min</td>
        <td data-day="sun">222</td>
        <td data-day="mon">222</td>
        <td data-day="tue">222</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Thanks to member @Filoxo for this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/filoxo/ta4QT/3/) file.

Comment: Are you getting data right now..? If not, this question is too broad. else what is the structure of data, and what have you tried..?

Comment: data pulled from SQL grouped by date. I just need to know how to populate a column and then loop the the next column.

Comment: As I said in the initial post, I currently have it configured to pull the data and place it in a 1 column table inside a floating DIV to make it "appear" like it's all in 1 table, however, with the hide/show functionalilty that @filoxo has assisted me with, I was hoping that there was an option with jQuery to populate fields based on column heading and table row name.

Comment: I had 2 completely different instances of this program under development and I was just assisted in getting the other version to work using the div's and single tables: [Other Stack Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682591/jquery-toggle-image-src-if-parent-class-is-clicked-hide-show/23683394?noredirect=1#23683394)